# I click an input radio and change an image src, by clicking again...how do I change the image back how it was?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

https://jsfiddle.net/Suiberu/rxu8wgxf/

```
//INPUT RADIO ON & OFF 
var prv;
var markIt = function(e) {
  if (prv === this && this.checked) {
    this.checked = false;
    prv = null;
  } else {
    prv = this;
  }
};

$(function() {
  $('input.limit_radio').on('click', markIt);
});


//CHANGE IMAGE
function changeImage(imgName) {
     image = document.getElementById('theimage');
     image.src = imgName;
}
```

Clicking on an input type radio.. and yes it has to be an input type radio,
I do manage to change an img src.
Thanks to some jquery code I can manage to turn off the input radio. But the changed image remains as it was changed in the first place.
So when I turn off the input type radio I would like to get back the original img src. 
How do I achieve this?

Sorry, but javascript or jquery are not my strongest skills, but you can verify what am I asking for just checking the url above.

Thanks!

Comment: check now https://jsfiddle.net/rxu8wgxf/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the onclick handler and added a data attribute to swap out the urls.

https://jsfiddle.net/jjwilly16/37yn9xzy/1/.

```
<img src="http://www.cbc.ca/i/img/theme/default/plus-up.png" name="theimage" id="theimage" data-alternate="https://www.ucl.ac.uk/2034/images/icons/arrow-blue-left.png"/>
```

```
/INPUT RADIO ON & OFF 
var prv;
var markIt = function(e) {
    if (prv === this && this.checked) {
    this.checked = false;
    prv = null;
  } else {
    prv = this;
  }
    var img = document.getElementById('theimage'),
        alternate = img.getAttribute('data-alternate'),
      src = img.src;
  img.src = alternate;
  img.setAttribute('data-alternate', src);

};

$(function() {
  $('input.limit_radio').on('click', markIt);
});
```

Comment: okey, this is a very good answer, thanks.
But i forgot to give more details about my problem, my fault.
Can you please check this new example? And you will understand my doubt. 
Instead of one input type radio, I have TWO.
At the beginning the image has a question mark.

Comment: sorry, https://jsfiddle.net/Suiberu/v6xja0yd/ this is the code.
As you can see, at the beginning the image has a question mark. so when you click the first input, the image changes, if you click the second input, the image changes again, but no matter if you turn off the inputs, the image remains as the last image selected. How can i go back to the original question mark by turning off any of the input radio??
thanks!

Comment: Ok, check this one: https://jsfiddle.net/jjwilly16/2L3pnhfj/. I basically just checked if the radio was checked on click, and if it isn't put the question mark back.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mouseup` event, remove and replace the original `<input type="radio">` element.

```js
$(function() {
  var sources = ["https://www.ucl.ac.uk/2034/images/icons/arrow-blue-left.png"
                , "http://www.cbc.ca/i/img/theme/default/plus-up.png"];

  var img = $("#theimage");

  var clicked = false;

  function changeImage(e) {
    
    img.attr("src", function() {
      var checked = e.target.checked;
      if (!clicked || checked) {
        var clone = e.target.outerHTML;
        $(e.target).remove();
        $(clone).insertAfter($("#theimage + br"));
        $(".limit_radio").prop("checked", !clicked ? true : !checked);
      }
      return (!clicked ? (clicked = true) : !checked) ? sources[0] : sources[1]
    });
  }

  $(document).on("mouseup", "input.limit_radio", changeImage)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<img src="http://www.cbc.ca/i/img/theme/default/plus-up.png" name="theimage" id="theimage" />
<br>
<input class="limit_radio" type="radio" name="edit_race" value="gnomin" id="race_gnomin">
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rxu8wgxf/5/

Comment: no, sorry, as i stated very clearly, it cant be a checkbox, it has to be a input type radio.
can you check this code? https://jsfiddle.net/Suiberu/v6xja0yd/ as i explained above, now this problem has two inputs type radio (or more) my doubt is... how do i go back to the original "question mark" image?